# Showing different output in different IDE

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, compiler-errors, dev-c++

I am solving challenges in hackerrank. I came across this [question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps). I am using Dev C++ in my laptop for solving problems and later upload the code into hackerrank. For some test cases, my local Dev C++ IDE showing correct output but hackerrank is showing the wrong output for the same test case.

Code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 

using namespace std;

bool ransomeNote(int m, int n, string magazine, string note) {

string temp = ""; int st = 0, end;
bool flag = false;
for (int i = 0; i < note.length(); i++) {
    
    if (note[i] != ' ') {
        temp += note[i];    
    
    } 
    if (note[i] == ' ' || i == note.length() - 1){
        
        
        if ((magazine.find(temp) != string::npos)) {
            
            st = magazine.find(temp);

            magazine.replace(st, temp.length() - 1, "");
            
            flag = true;
            temp = "";
            
            
        } else {
        
            flag = false;
            return flag;
        }
        
    }
}
return flag;    
}


int main() {

int m,n;

cin >> m >> n;

string magazine;
string note;
fflush(stdin);

  
getline(cin, magazine);

getline(cin, note);

if (ransomeNote(m, n, magazine, note)) {

    cout << "Yes";
} else {
    cout << "No";
}


return 0;
}
```

Output in my IDE :

[image]

Hackerrank output :
[image]

For test cases with output **No** both are showing the same output but for output **Yes** they are showing different outputs.

Is there any problem in my code?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: "Is there any problem in my code?" - there's one obvious one: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the question

Comment: Note that `fflush(stdin)` is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush).

Comment: @G.M wrong link, for C++ its that one: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush

Comment: expanding on Jespers comment, it should be no surprise that you get different results, because your code is non-portable. Read here: 
[Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: @G.M yeah, fflush(stdin) is the problem. Replaced with cin.ignore(); Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thanks for your information about #include<stdlib/stdc++.h> :)@idclev 463035818 and Jesper Juhl

Comment: @idclev463035818 while using `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is indeed bad due to portability, it should not be the reason for the different results.